# unable to access server from my android device after changing router

Tags: android, networking, localhost

I can connect to my localhost(My Laptop) using my android device using the router at our house. But when I went to school to test my app using a different router, I can't anymore connect to my localhost. Since my Laptop is in DHCP mode, its ip changed and I also changed the url from `String url = "http://192.168.254.103"` to `String url ="http://192.168.1.103"`.

Does any of you guys encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firewall will block the host connection. So disable firewall connection in your school server system and try this or given permission to the device.